The "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/systemback" command does not work
I'm trying to create a Live ISO of my linux distribution using a tutorial and to do so it tells me to enter this command:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/systemback

problem it returns me this error:
shell answer
Can you help me to solve this problem please
Thanks in advance

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Is this your tutorial: A Quick Guide to Using Systemback for Ubuntu Backup. Searching further down the Google result yields this, but the version she saved on her repo only goes to 22.04

You should probably have noted the "SUPPORT ENDED" (as shown below).
Currently supported Ubuntu releases:
- 14.04.X LTS
- 15.04
- 15.10
- 16.04.X LTS
- 16.10

* DEVELOPMENT AND SUPPORT ENDED *

